# partitioning & formatting additional hard drives

Tags: partitioning, format

I have a 4 TB spinner HD on which I have installed my OS.
I have 3, M.2, 1-TB  PCIe SSDs that are mounted directly to the MOBO; this question is about the SSDs.
I can see them in G parted as unallocated spaces. I can partition them using  Gpt or MsDos, but I've read that I don't have to and that I could use LVM to my advantage here.

What I'd like to end up with are distinct hard drive designations. The Spinner being one, and each of the SSDs as 2, 3, & 4, by whatever designation the system uses, but distinct and not all one 7 terabyte space.
So, Should I partition the SSDs with G parted?
thx

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release, nor details of what you're trying to achieve (*that I can understand anyway*)   *The various tools all do the same thing, so use whichever tool you know/find-easier, and partition it exactly how you want it*

Comment: You can use Gparted to create GUID partition tables (aka GPT) and then create a single primary partition spanning each SSD. Assuming you are using Ubuntu you may use `ext4` as the partition type.

Comment: thank you for that

Comment: Yes I believe it does  thanks

Comment: Was there some reason not to put install on the faster M.2 SSD drives? Are they SATA or NVMe M.2 drives? The only reason to use MBR is if you have a system from before 2012 and have to install Windows. Microsoft has required UEFI/gpt since Windows 8 released in 2012. Ubuntu will let you use MBR with UEFI but really should not. You can use gpt with BIOS boot with Ubuntu, if using BIOS. Do not know LVM, has advantages for servers where you may want to dynamically resize volumes, but LVM is normally inside a partition.

Comment: Yah I want to be able to swap hard drives out that have different operating systems on them but I didn't want to dual boot